# how can i draw this graph in mathplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I want to draw graphs on the screen with Matplotlib using Jupyter Notebook. I want to show dates on the horizontal axis and data on the vertical axis. I can show data on the vertical axis. However, on the horizontal axis it shows the sequence number of the dates, not the dates. How can I solve this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from seaborn import heatmap
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import matplotlib.style as mplstyle
```

Here I have installed the libraries. Then I pulled the data and processed it.

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
csv_file_url = 'http://www.facadium.com.tr/cvd19/nisansonunakadarolanveriler.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(csv_file_url, sep = ',', index_col=0)
pd.set_option("display.max.rows", None)
dataset.head(2000)
```

Then I plotted the data from the entire dataset.

```
for i, col in enumerate(dataset.columns.tolist()):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    x_axis = dataset.index.values
    y_axis = dataset[col].values
    plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis, label=col,marker='o')
    plt.title(col)
    plt.xlabel("Günler")
    plt.ylabel("Veriler")
    counter = 0
    for a, b in zip(x_axis, y_axis):
        counter +=1
        if counter % 60 == 0:
            plt.annotate(str(b), xy=(a,b))
```

I listed the data.

```
dataset_shifted = dataset.iloc[0:,:]
dataset_shifted.head(2000)
dataset_shifted.describe()
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
dataset_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(dataset_shifted.values)
dataset_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(dataset_shifted),columns=dataset_shifted.columns)
dataset_scaled.index = dataset_shifted.index
dataset_scaled.head(2000)
```

and I created the heatmap with correlation

```
korelasyon = dataset_scaled.corr()
korelasyon
heatmap(korelasyon, xticklabels=dataset_shifted.columns, yticklabels=dataset_shifted.columns)
```

I then try to extract predictions from the data. Here I want it to predict data number 4 from data 1,2,4.

```
x = dataset_scaled.iloc[:,[1,2,4]]
y = dataset_scaled.iloc[:,[4]]
x
y
mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(75,), max_iter=10000, learning_rate_init=0.05, random_state=41)
mlp.fit(x.values, y.values)
y_predicted = mlp.predict(x.values)
y_predicted
y.values.round(3)
```

I find r2s and arrays in the results I get from here.

```
mean_squared_error(y.values, y_predicted)
r2_score(y.values, y_predicted)
mlp.coefs_[0].round(3)
mlp.intercepts_
```

Then I try to graph the data I get. However, I want to see the dates on the horizontal axis and the data on the vertical axis while I am displaying my data.

```
ax= y.plot(linestyle='-')
plt.xlabel("Günler",
         fontdict={
             'family' : 'Times New Roman',
             'color' : 'black',
             'size' : 14
         })

plt.ylabel("Veriler",
         fontdict={
             'family' : 'Times New Roman',
             'color' : 'black',
             'size' : 14
         })
plt.title("Tek Katmanlı Ağır Hasta Sayısı Grafiği",
         fontdict={
             'family' : 'Times New Roman',
             'color' : 'black',
             'size' : 20
         })
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

In the graph I got here, the data comes in as dates on the horizontal axis, but the data is scaled between 0-1 on the vertical axis. I wanted to try this instead.

```
plt.plot(y.values.round(3)*5980, label = 'Gerçek Değer',linestyle="-", color='green')
plt.plot(y_predicted*5980, label = 'Tahmini Değer',linestyle='dashed', color='red')

plt.legend(loc="upper left")

plt.style.use(['seaborn-white'])
plt.grid()
```

Comment: In your first paragraph you mention you want to change the format of your dates. In one of the last paragraphs of your post you say 

> However, I want to see the dates on the horizontal axis and the data on the vertical axis while I am displaying my data.

Are you trying to change your data or your dates?

Answer (score 0):

actually i want this. I want to show dates and data in chart. But the data is displayed as 1 and 0. I want to see this data. I don't want to see numbers 1 and 0